# Как реализовать метод, возвращающий класс и создать public переменную этого класса?

Tags: java, generics, интернационализация

Есть метод, который читает из файла настроек язык. Пока 2 варианта языка: "ENG" и "RUS".
Есть словарь :

```
final public сlass rus { 
final public word1 = "smth...";
final public word2 = "smthelse...";
... }
```

.

```
final public сlass eng { 
final public word1 = "smth...";
final public word2 = "smthelse...";
... }
```

Мне необходимо написать метод `Settings.setLanguage(String language)`, который будет возвращать класс `rus` или `eng`, и затем создать поле `glossary`.
Словарь используется в коде следующим образом: `glossary.word1; glossary.word2;`

Comment: Это неправильный подход, надо локализацию хранить в каком-нить конфиг файле и при обращении читать его и создавать глоссарий.

Comment: Ты явно делаешь что-то не то

Comment: Чем этот способ уступает ResourseBundle и Locale? словарик не большой, на 100 слов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы используете неправильный подход для локализации приложения на Java. Для этого придумали [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). Этот подход гибок и удобен при разработке, поскольку добавление нового языка не требует изменений клиентского кода. Плюс в локализации может участвовать человек, незнакомый с программированием.

Небольшой пример по работе с локализацией:

1. Создать текстовый стандартный конфигурационный файл (для языка по умолчанию в приложении). Имя файла должно всегда начинаться с имени класса `ResourceBundle` и иметь расширение `.properties`. Пример содержимого`LabelsBundle.properties`:

   > s1 = computer
   >   s2 = disk
   >   s3 = monitor
   >   s4 = keyboard

   Файл представляет собой набор пар ключ-значение. Ключи необходимо продумать заранее, поскольку их изменение влечет изменение клиентского кода.
2. Добавляете дополнительные конфигурационные файлы для поддерживаемых языков приложения. Например, `LabelsBundle_ru.properties`. И переводите значения ключей.
3. Объявляете список локалей непосредственно в коде приложения:

   `Locale[] supportedLocales = {
       Locale.RUSSIAN,
       Locale.ENGLISH
   };`
4. Связываете между собой локали, конфигурационные файлы и `ResourceBundle`:
   `ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LabelsBundle", currentLocale);`

   Для получения значения по ключу используем код вида: `String value = labels.getString(key);`

Более подробное описание с примером доступно на официальном сайте [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html).

Answer (score 2):

Если решать задачу в таком ключе, то получится примерно такой код:

`Settings.java`:

```
package ru.test;

public class Settings {
    public static Language glossary = Settings.setLanguage("ru");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(glossary.getWord1());
        System.out.println(glossary.getWord2());
    }

    public static Language setLanguage(String language) {
        switch(language) {
            case "ru":
                return new Rus();
            case "en":
                return new Eng();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Передан неизвестный язык '" + language + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

`Language.java`:

```
package ru.test;

public interface Language {
    public String getWord1();
    public String getWord2();
}
```

`Rus.java`:

```
package ru.test;

public class Rus implements Language {
    final private String word1 = "слово 1";
    final private String word2 = "слово 2";

    @Override
    public String getWord1() {
        return word1;
    }
    @Override
    public String getWord2() {
        return word2;
    }
}
```

`Eng.java`:

```
package ru.test;

public class Eng implements Language {
    final private String word1 = "word 1";
    final private String word2 = "word 2";

    @Override
    public String getWord1() {
        return word1;
    }
    @Override
    public String getWord2() {
        return word2;
    }
}
```

Обращаться к полям классов `Rus` и `Eng` напрямую не получится в такой реализации, поэтому используются геттеры. Если убрать `final` у этих полей, то можно переписать код через прямое использование полей.

Приведённый код представляет собой некоторое подобие паттерна проектирования [Абстрактная фабрика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29).

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите именно таким путем пойти, то как вариант:

1. Заведите интерфейс, от которого унаследуйте оба словаря(в вашем случае, к примеру, glossary)
2. Класс-перечисление(enum, как вариант с элементами ENG, RUS)
3. Мапу, где ключем будет класс-перечисление, значением - glossary(интерфейс). Заполните мапу как ENG-> eng, RUS-> rus
4. Поле типа glossary(Можно сделать статикой), куда вы будете сохранять реализацию(rus или eng) в зависимости от переданного параметра в Settings.setLanguage(String language).
5. Юзать уже glossary(Он будет содержать необходимую реализацию)